# How to clear the Julia's REPL log?

Tags: julia

One of the cool features of Julia's REPL is that you can see and recall all code blocks you have written so far in the REPL. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> I can see them all. Also, it's possible to scroll between them using <kbd>↑</kbd> key and recall them by <kbd>Enter</kbd> or double left-click. The issue is that, in my case, it shows a number at the end of the log:
[image]

I guess this number indicates the total code blocks logged so far. How can I clear this kind of history and log? Each time I execute REPL, I think it tries to read all the records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the logs in `C://Users/<USER>/.julia/logs/repl_history.jl`. After deleting all of its content, the logs will be removed.
[image]